# Кавычки в названиях худож.текстов

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему названия художественных произведений в учебниках по литературе пишут без кавычек. Как объяснить ученику, если на уроке русского языка говорим, что названия книг, газет и т.д. пишутся в кавычках и с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду учебник или хрестоматию? В учебниках при анализе текстов не видела написаний без кавычек, а если это хрестоматия, собственно текст, то без кавычек, как любой заголовок за исключением цитат. А зачем здесь кавычки? Они ставятся в названиях, являющихся приложением.

Всё по правилам. На уроках русского языка мы объясняем, что кавычки - это знак препинания, средство выделения чужой речи (цитат), слов с условным значением и некоторых названий, в том числе литературных произведений. Если это название текста перед самим текстом, то выделять его незачем, оно стоит отдельно.

Comment: Все теперь понятно. Спасибо большое.